# Extract JavaScript variable (feature example): how to improve it?

Tags: functions, object-motions, user-commands, user-input

I am a Vim newbie with one week experience and I'm already enjoying it.

I've successfully written an (ugly) command+function+mapping with which I can extract some code to a new variable in JavaScript. This is my code, it works with motions (\jsexviw) and selection in visual mode:

```
command! -range -nargs=1 JsExVar normal `<v`>d^[i<args>^[Ovar <args> = (^[pa);^[

function! FnJsExVar(type)
    silent exec 'JsExVar '.input("Variable name: ")
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <expr> <Leader>jsexv ":JsExVar ".input("Variable name: ")."<cr>"
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsexv :set opfunc=FnJsExVar<CR>g@
```

I still don't fully understand the different ways of executing things, so I assume the code can be improved and cleaned a lot. Thanks in advance for any correction and suggestion.

----- EDIT ------

I've refactored a bit to avoid duplicated input("Variable name: ") but now I have a weird (0) param when calling the function from the command:

```
command! -range JsExVar call ExecJsExVar(0) 

vnoremap <silent> <expr> <Leader>jsexv ":JsExVar<cr>"
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsexv :set opfunc=ExecJsExVar<CR>g@

function! ExecJsExVar(type)
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal `<v`>di".varname."^["
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = ^["
    silent exec "normal pa;^["
endfunction
```

----- (more) EDIT ------

Ok, it wasn't really working with motions. I think this works... but the question is: can this be done with one function?

```
command! -range JsExVar call JavascriptExtractVariable(0) 
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :JsExVar<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :set opfunc=JavascriptExtractVariable2<CR>g@

function! JavascriptExtractVariable(type)
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal `<v`>di".varname.""
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = ("
    silent exec "normal pa);"
endfunction

function! JavascriptExtractVariable2(type)
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal `[v`]di".varname.""
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = ("
    silent exec "normal pa);"
endfunction
```

(re-edited because wrong code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994276/defining-a-new-vim-operator-with-a-parameter/8998136#8998136) I've been able to make it work without the command and with one function. And I learnt what that argument was for, how to use optional arguments and the func-range modifier:

```
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :call JsExtractVariable(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :set opfunc=JsExtractVariable<CR>g@
function! JsExtractVariable(vt, ...) range
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal ".SelectByMode(a:0)."di".varname."^["
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = (^[pa);^["
endfunction

function! SelectByMode(isvisual)
    return (a:isvisual ? "`<v`>" : "`[v`]")
endfunction
```

I post this as an answer because it's the kind of improvement I was looking for. Any other suggestion will be welcome, thanks.

Comment: "I've been able to make it work without the command and with one function." There's two functions in your code ;).

Comment: Hehe, @Rich you're right, but you know, 2nd function it's only for reusing... not like the ugly JavascriptExtractVariable / JavascriptExtractVariable2 functions :P

Comment: I was attempting to be funny :(.

Comment: It looks like a bug in my irony detector, mea culpa :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things you might not already know:

### Including Special Characters in String Constants

Instead of inserting special characters literally, by typing e.g. <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, you can use the forms described in `:help string`:

```
silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = (\<Esc>pa);\<Esc>"
```

This makes it easier to see what the code is doing when viewed in contexts which do not highlight the special characters, and is better for cut and paste (I had to edit all the ESC characters in your code when copying it into my `.vimrc` to try it out)

### Simple Variable Extraction

This isn't really the sort of information you were looking for, but you can perform a more basic version of your edits by using <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> in insert mode to insert the previously inserted text.

From visual mode:

1. Type `c` followed by your new variable name and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave insert mode.
2. Type `Ovar` (including the trailing space)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> to add in the variable name again.
4. Type `= ;<Esc>` (including the leading space) to complete the line.
5. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to `put` the value of the new variable before the semi-colon.

To do the same from normal mode, simply add in the motion after you press <kbd>c</kbd> in step 1.

You could of course extract Steps 2–5 into a normal mode mapping which you could then use after performing step 1 manually (from either visual or normal mode):

```
execute "nnoremap <Leader>jsxv Ovar \<C-A> = ;\<Esc>P"
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich, great info!
I didn't know <C-A>, it looks usefull.
And I've been using special characters in both styles with some fears of the differences.